# print the output of a long function - python

Tags: python, xcode, operating-system, system

hi guys i want to print the output of the function xcode_version with only the version number , my code here contains 2 error , 
the first one is : print("Xcode Version : %s%s%s"%(G,R)xcode_version())
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
the second one is , when the command is executed , it dosent grep the version number only like it is supposed to do ( Xcode 7.0.1 ) but it prints the hole xcodebuild -version command , with the result : Xcode 7.0.1 Build version 7A1001
solutions for these 2 errors ?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#
#Putty-On-Osx By Fedy Wesleti
import sys
import os
import subprocess

G = '\033[92m' #green
Y = '\033[93m' #yellow
B = '\033[94m' #blue
R = '\033[91m' #red

def xcode_version():
    try:
        xcode = subprocess.call(["xcodebuild","-version","&","grep","xcode"])
        print(xcode)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
            print("Not Installed")
        else:
            # Something else went wrong while trying to run `wget`
            raise


print("Xcode Version : %s%s%s"%(G,R)xcode_version())
```

Comment: 1. print("Xcode Version : %s%s%s"%(G,R,xcode_version()). 2. not sure how to get it.

Comment: the output of what you sad is this : 'python putty-on-osx.py
Xcode 7.0.1
Build version 7A1001
0
Xcode Version : None'